# Translate PostgreSQL query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I got stuck on translating this PostgreSQL query to SQL Server query.

```
  WHEN (md."type" = 'HAAS' and md."process" = 'machine') THEN CAST(
    (
      MAX(
        EXTRACT(
          EPOCH
          FROM
            cast(md."haas_power_on_time" as interval)
        )
      ) - MIN(
        EXTRACT(
          EPOCH
          FROM
            cast(md."haas_power_on_time" as interval)
        )
      )
    ) as varchar
  )
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain what the logic should be doing.

Comment: You don't appear to have started yet - so where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the difference between the max and min values in seconds -- converted to a string for some reason.  If so:

```
 WHEN md."type" = 'HAAS' AND md."process" = 'machine'
 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(md."haas_power_on_time"), MAX(md."haas_power_on_time")) AS VARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is the haas_power_on_time is in EPOCH format, like 05130:08:07. That is the reason why Postgres query using   EXTRACT( EPOCH from source). Can you tell me how to EPOCH  interval in DateDiff instead of second?

Comment: @ChristianMok . . . My understanding is that EPOCH is the number of days since 1970-01-01 (that is how Postgres defines it https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).  I don't recognize the format in your comment.